# How to add subview of some view in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner programming android. I am searching for info how to create transparent sub view  on current window layout.

I have created simple layout this is source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Simple text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to create a View when navigation button is pressed. That View i want to add on top of this layout with transparent about 40%. It should look something like this:

[image]

Also it should be easy to add Buttons, Drop box or else and i could easy remove this View.

Maybe someone did this and could me share ideas, how do do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: use RelativeLayout to show one view on other view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this and do programatically

```
view.getBackground().setAlpha(100); // to make background transparent
```

you can use PopupWindow to show on top of parent view as following

```
View mainview ;
PopupWindow popupwindow;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     mainview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
     setContentView(mainview);

    // load sub menu from xml layout in popupwindow
      View submenu_popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.submenu_popup, null, false);

// make backgraound transparent of popup submenu
        submenu_popup.getBackground().setAlpha(100);

        popupwindow = new PopupWindow(submenu_popup ,300,300,false);
        popupwindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupwindow.setTouchable(true);

}


// call it on click of button or menu to show submenu
public void onClickButton(){

    int x=0,y=0;
// show popupwindow on x, y position in main view (parent view) by using this
    popupwindow.showAtLocation(mainview , Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should learn how to use  "android:theme" property